# Splitting a 2-column very long table into various multiple columns across different pages

Tags: header-footer, page-breaking, longtable

I have a 645-row table to be included in one article appendix. Such table has only two narrow columns where each row is composed of a Month-Year in the first cell and one date in the last cell of the row (e.g.: MMM-YY & YYYYyMMmDD\\). The table caption is "Schedule", the header is Month & Date\\, and for some 12 dates I would include a single common footnote observation note in the footer (something like, "Industrial action days.").

Rather than a longtable that would span across more than 20 portrait A4 pages with only two narrow columns lost in the middle of the page, I was wondering if there is a way of automatically putting the first (say 3 or 4 or 5) two-column pages side by side in one single "table" (or the first part of a longtable) until they fill the \textwidth of the first page before repeating the whole process over the next pages and finish accommodating all the 645 rows of table data. As a result, instead of more than 20 pages, such appendix table would have 4 to 6 pages, where the third column of each page follows from the first, the fourth from the second, and so on.

The solutions I have seen so far seem to encourage the use of the tabular environment but that entails manually splitting the tables (which I can do but I find this sub-optimal, first, because I have too many rows; second, if I change the table font size, or the margins, or the orientation of the page, I have to reorder everything manually again). If I had to do this manually, I would be able to fit 8 columns along the text width, each page would have 38 rows and the table header would be:

```
multicolumn{1}{c}{Month} & 
multicolumn{1}{c}{Date} & 
multicolumn{1}{c}{Month} &
multicolumn{1}{c}{Date} & 
multicolumn{1}{c}{Month} & 
multicolumn{1}{c}{Date} & 
multicolumn{1}{c}{Month} & 
multicolumn{1}{c}{Date}Would anyone know of a better way to handle such a table in a more automatic way?
```

By the way, I prefer to add footnotes manually in the footer of the (long) table. E.g., in a longtable environment, I would have a row that would say:

```
Mar-49 & 1949M03D20$^{\dagger}$ whereas in the footer, I would have something like:

\\[-2ex]
\midrule 
\\[-2ex]  
\multicolumn{8}{l}{\noindent\parbox{\textwidth}{\footnotesize{\textit{\textbf{Notes}}:
$\dagger$ Industrial action days.}}}\\ 
\multicolumn{8}{r}{\textit{Continued $\ldots$}}\\ 
\endfoot
```

If there is an automatic way to perform what I am willing to achieve, would you also happen to know how I could obtain the same kind of manual footnote as in above? The same question would apply to the header of such a longtable.

I would really appreciate any comments as I have been struggling with the formatting of this table for a while now. I am sorry if this question is an exact repeat. In case it is, could you please refer me to where the answer is? Thank you very much.

NB: Just to have an idea of the article page layout and the packages I am using, in the document preamble, as well as some sample data, I have the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,openbib,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{10}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.1cm}
\setlength{\headheight}{0cm}
\setlength{\headsep}{0cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\topskip}{0cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{16cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{23.5cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{10 mm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{acknowledgement}[theorem]{Acknowledgement}
\newtheorem{algorithm}[theorem]{Algorithm}
\newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Axiom}
\newtheorem{case}[theorem]{Case}
\newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim}
\newtheorem{conclusion}[theorem]{Conclusion}
\newtheorem{condition}[theorem]{Condition}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{criterion}[theorem]{Criterion}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{Notation}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{solution}[theorem]{Solution}
\newtheorem{summary}[theorem]{Summary}
\newenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\noindent\textbf{#1.} }{\ \rule{0.5em}{0.5em}}
\newcolumntype{d}{D{.}{.}{3.4}}
\makeatletter
\def\@biblabel#1{\hspace*{-\labelsep}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Main Section}

This article includes an example of an appendix longtable with 645 rows of data in only two columns to be split into various two-column to fill one page and carry on filling over the next pages.

\bigskip

\appendix
\section{Appendix}
\begin{center}
\begin{small}
\begin{longtable}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.5\textwidth} 
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{.5\textwidth}}

    Oct-53 & 1953M10D20$^{\dagger}$ \kill

\caption{Schedule}\\
\toprule[1pt]
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Month} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Date}\\[0.5ex]
\toprule
\endfirsthead

\caption[ ] {Schedule \textit{Continued $\ldots$}}\\
\toprule[1pt]
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Month} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Date}\\[0.5ex]
\toprule
\endhead

\\[-2ex]
\midrule 
\\[-2ex]  
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\noindent\parbox{\textwidth}{\footnotesize{\textit{\textbf{Notes}}:
$\dagger$ Industrial action days.}}}\\ 
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\textit{Continued $\ldots$}}\\ 
\endfoot

\\[-2ex]
\bottomrule[1pt]
\\[-2ex]
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\noindent\parbox{\textwidth}{\footnotesize{\textit{\textbf{Notes}}:
$\dagger$ Industrial action days.}}}\\ 
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\textit{The End}}\\
\endlastfoot

Jan-49 & 1949M01D20 \\
Feb-49 & 1949M02D20 \\
Mar-49 & 1949M03D20$^{\dagger}$ \\
Apr-49 & 1949M04D20 \\
May-49 & 1949M05D20 \\
Jun-49 & 1949M06D20 \\
Jul-49 & 1949M07D20 \\
Aug-49 & 1949M08D20 \\
Sep-49 & 1949M09D20 \\
Oct-49 & 1949M10D20 \\
Nov-49 & 1949M11D20 \\
Dec-49 & 1949M12D20 \\
Jan-50 & 1950M01D20 \\
Feb-50 & 1950M02D20 \\
Mar-50 & 1950M03D20$^{\dagger}$ \\
Apr-50 & 1950M04D20 \\
May-50 & 1950M05D20 \\
Jun-50 & 1950M06D20 \\
Jul-50 & 1950M07D20 \\
Aug-50 & 1950M08D20 \\
Sep-50 & 1950M09D20 \\
Oct-50 & 1950M10D20 \\
Nov-50 & 1950M11D20 \\
Dec-50 & 1950M12D20 \\
Jan-51 & 1951M01D20 \\
Feb-51 & 1951M02D20 \\
Mar-51 & 1951M03D20 \\
Apr-51 & 1951M04D20 \\
May-51 & 1951M05D20 \\
Jun-51 & 1951M06D20 \\
Jul-51 & 1951M07D20 \\
Aug-51 & 1951M08D20 \\
Sep-51 & 1951M09D20 \\
Oct-51 & 1951M10D20 \\
Nov-51 & 1951M11D20 \\
Dec-51 & 1951M12D20 \\
Jan-52 & 1952M01D20 \\
Feb-52 & 1952M02D20 \\
Mar-52 & 1952M03D20 \\
Apr-52 & 1952M04D20 \\
May-52 & 1952M05D20 \\
Jun-52 & 1952M06D20 \\
Jul-52 & 1952M07D20 \\
Aug-52 & 1952M08D20 \\
Sep-52 & 1952M09D20 \\
Oct-52 & 1952M10D20 \\
Nov-52 & 1952M11D20 \\
Dec-52 & 1952M12D20 \\
Jan-53 & 1953M01D20 \\
Feb-53 & 1953M02D20 \\
Mar-53 & 1953M03D20 \\
Apr-53 & 1953M04D20 \\
May-53 & 1953M05D20 \\
Jun-53 & 1953M06D20 \\
Jul-53 & 1953M07D20 \\
Aug-53 & 1953M08D20 \\
Sep-53 & 1953M09D20 \\
Oct-53 & 1953M10D20$^{\dagger}$ \\
Nov-53 & 1953M11D20 \\
Dec-53 & 1953M12D20 \\
Jan-54 & 1954M01D20 \\
Feb-54 & 1954M02D20 \\
Mar-54 & 1954M03D20 \\
Apr-54 & 1954M04D20 \\
May-54 & 1954M05D20 \\
Jun-54 & 1954M06D20 \\
Jul-54 & 1954M07D20 \\
Aug-54 & 1954M08D20 \\
Sep-54 & 1954M09D20 \\
Oct-54 & 1954M10D20 \\
Nov-54 & 1954M11D20 \\
Dec-54 & 1954M12D20 \\
Jan-55 & 1955M01D20 \\
Feb-55 & 1955M02D20 \\
Mar-55 & 1955M03D20 \\
Apr-55 & 1955M04D20 \\
May-55 & 1955M05D20 \\
Jun-55 & 1955M06D20 \\
Jul-55 & 1955M07D20 \\
Aug-55 & 1955M08D20 \\
Sep-55 & 1955M09D20 \\
Oct-55 & 1955M10D20 \\
Nov-55 & 1955M11D20 \\
Dec-55 & 1955M12D20 \\
Jan-56 & 1956M01D20 \\
Feb-56 & 1956M02D20 \\
Mar-56 & 1956M03D20 \\
Apr-56 & 1956M04D20 \\
May-56 & 1956M05D20 \\
Jun-56 & 1956M06D20 \\
Jul-56 & 1956M07D20 \\
Aug-56 & 1956M08D20 \\
Sep-56 & 1956M09D20 \\
Oct-56 & 1956M10D20 \\
Nov-56 & 1956M11D20 \\
Dec-56 & 1956M12D20 \\
Jan-57 & 1957M01D20 \\
Feb-57 & 1957M02D20 \\
Mar-57 & 1957M03D20 \\
Apr-57 & 1957M04D20 \\
May-57 & 1957M05D20 \\
Jun-57 & 1957M06D20 \\
Jul-57 & 1957M07D20$^{\dagger}$ \\
Aug-57 & 1957M08D20 \\
Sep-57 & 1957M09D20 \\
Oct-57 & 1957M10D20 \\
Nov-57 & 1957M11D20 \\
Dec-57 & 1957M12D20 \\
Jan-58 & 1958M01D20 \\
Feb-58 & 1958M02D20 \\
Mar-58 & 1958M03D20 \\
Apr-58 & 1958M04D20 \\
May-58 & 1958M05D20 \\
Jun-58 & 1958M06D20 \\
Jul-58 & 1958M07D20 \\
Aug-58 & 1958M08D20 \\
Sep-58 & 1958M09D20 \\
Oct-58 & 1958M10D20 \\
Nov-58 & 1958M11D20 \\
Dec-58 & 1958M12D20 \\
Jan-59 & 1959M01D20 \\
Feb-59 & 1959M02D20 \\
Mar-59 & 1959M03D20 \\
Apr-59 & 1959M04D20 \\
May-59 & 1959M05D20$^{\dagger}$ \\
Jun-59 & 1959M06D20$^{\dagger}$ \\
Jul-59 & 1959M07D20 \\
Aug-59 & 1959M08D20 \\
Sep-59 & 1959M09D20 \\
Oct-59 & 1959M10D20 \\
Nov-59 & 1959M11D20 \\
Dec-59 & 1959M12D20 \\
Jan-60 & 1960M01D20 \\
Feb-60 & 1960M02D20 \\
Mar-60 & 1960M03D20 \\
Apr-60 & 1960M04D20 \\
May-60 & 1960M05D20 \\
Jun-60 & 1960M06D20 \\
Jul-60 & 1960M07D20 \\
Aug-60 & 1960M08D20 \\
Sep-60 & 1960M09D20 \\
Oct-60 & 1960M10D20 \\
Nov-60 & 1960M11D20 \\
Dec-60 & 1960M12D20 \\
Jan-61 & 1961M01D20 \\
Feb-61 & 1961M02D20 \\
Mar-61 & 1961M03D20 \\
Apr-61 & 1961M04D20 \\
May-61 & 1961M05D20 \\
Jun-61 & 1961M06D20 \\
Jul-61 & 1961M07D20 \\
Aug-61 & 1961M08D20 \\
Sep-61 & 1961M09D20 \\
Oct-61 & 1961M10D20 \\
Nov-61 & 1961M11D20 \\
Dec-61 & 1961M12D20 \\
Jan-62 & 1962M01D20 \\
Feb-62 & 1962M02D20 \\
Mar-62 & 1962M03D20 \\
Apr-62 & 1962M04D20 \\
May-62 & 1962M05D20 \\
Jun-62 & 1962M06D20 \\
Jul-62 & 1962M07D20 \\
Aug-62 & 1962M08D20 \\
Sep-62 & 1962M09D20 \\
Oct-62 & 1962M10D20 \\
Nov-62 & 1962M11D20 \\
Dec-62 & 1962M12D20 \\
Jan-63 & 1963M01D20 \\
Feb-63 & 1963M02D20 \\
Mar-63 & 1963M03D20$^{\dagger}$ \\
Apr-63 & 1963M04D20 \\
May-63 & 1963M05D20 \\
Jun-63 & 1963M06D20 \\
Jul-63 & 1963M07D20 \\
Aug-63 & 1963M08D20 \\
Sep-63 & 1963M09D20 \\
Oct-63 & 1963M10D20 \\
Nov-63 & 1963M11D20 \\
Dec-63 & 1963M12D20 \\
Jan-64 & 1964M01D20 \\
Feb-64 & 1964M02D20 \\
Mar-64 & 1964M03D20 \\
Apr-64 & 1964M04D20 \\
May-64 & 1964M05D20 \\
Jun-64 & 1964M06D20 \\
Jul-64 & 1964M07D20 \\
Aug-64 & 1964M08D20 \\
Sep-64 & 1964M09D20 \\
Oct-64 & 1964M10D20 \\
Nov-64 & 1964M11D20 \\
Dec-64 & 1964M12D20 \\
Jan-65 & 1965M01D20$^{\dagger}$ \\
Feb-65 & 1965M02D20 \\
Mar-65 & 1965M03D20 \\
Apr-65 & 1965M04D20 \\
May-65 & 1965M05D20 \\
Jun-65 & 1965M06D20 \\
Jul-65 & 1965M07D20 \\
Aug-65 & 1965M08D20 \\
Sep-65 & 1965M09D20 \\
Oct-65 & 1965M10D20 \\
Nov-65 & 1965M11D20 \\
Dec-65 & 1965M12D20 \\
Jan-66 & 1966M01D20 \\
Feb-66 & 1966M02D20 \\
Mar-66 & 1966M03D20 \\
Apr-66 & 1966M04D20 \\
May-66 & 1966M05D20 \\
Jun-66 & 1966M06D20 \\
Jul-66 & 1966M07D20 \\
Aug-66 & 1966M08D20 \\
Sep-66 & 1966M09D20 \\
Oct-66 & 1966M10D20 \\
Nov-66 & 1966M11D20 \\
Dec-66 & 1966M12D20 \\
Jan-67 & 1967M01D20 \\
Feb-67 & 1967M02D20 \\
Mar-67 & 1967M03D20 \\
Apr-67 & 1967M04D20 \\
May-67 & 1967M05D20 \\
Jun-67 & 1967M06D20 \\
Jul-67 & 1967M07D20 \\
Aug-67 & 1967M08D20 \\
Sep-67 & 1967M09D20 \\
Oct-67 & 1967M10D20 \\
Nov-67 & 1967M11D20 \\
Dec-67 & 1967M12D20 \\
Jan-68 & 1968M01D20 \\
Feb-68 & 1968M02D20 \\
Mar-68 & 1968M03D20 \\
Apr-68 & 1968M04D20 \\
May-68 & 1968M05D20 \\
Jun-68 & 1968M06D20 \\
Jul-68 & 1968M07D20 \\
Aug-68 & 1968M08D20 \\
Sep-68 & 1968M09D20 \\
Oct-68 & 1968M10D20 \\
Nov-68 & 1968M11D20 \\
Dec-68 & 1968M12D20 \\
Jan-69 & 1969M01D20 \\
Feb-69 & 1969M02D20 \\
Mar-69 & 1969M03D20 \\
Apr-69 & 1969M04D20 \\
May-69 & 1969M05D20 \\
Jun-69 & 1969M06D20 \\
Jul-69 & 1969M07D20 \\
Aug-69 & 1969M08D20 \\
Sep-69 & 1969M09D20 \\
Oct-69 & 1969M10D20 \\
Nov-69 & 1969M11D20 \\
Dec-69 & 1969M12D20 \\
Jan-70 & 1970M01D20 \\

\end{longtable}
\end{small}
\end{center}
\label{tab:DeepHistory_GDP}%
\bigskip
\clearpage

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{Smith and Jones 2008} Smith and Jones (2008). Real Policy. ECB WP100.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you can settle for `twocloumn` you can use `supertabular`. Or else, you have to do something with `pgfplotstable`.

Comment: Many thanks for your comment Harish. I am sorry, but let me see if I understood you correctly.

Comment: I have the feeling that when you say [twocolumn], you mean that my whole document only has two columns. Just in case, I am not using (and do not want to use) two columns accross my whole article. In case supertabular could do that automatically, could you please tell me how to do so? As for pgfplotstable, the command /pgfplots/table/select equal part entry of ={<part no>}{<part count>} seems to do what I would like to achieve; but how could it automatically compute the number of columns to be used? Thanks indeed again, Mauri.

Comment: Can you post a complete document with a sample data?

Comment: Dear Harish, I have just edited the end of my post so as to include some sample data. My original table is much longer than that (it has 645 rows). Many thanks for your attention!

Comment: Well, if anyone else would feel like generously sharing your knowledge, I would be more than grateful!

Comment: You have to decide number of columns manually. Another possibility is switch to two column temporarily and use supertabular.

Answer (score 2):

You can put groups of three consecutive entries on the same row without too much change to the markup.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,openbib,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{10}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.1cm}
\setlength{\headheight}{0cm}
\setlength{\headsep}{0cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\topskip}{0cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{16cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{23.5cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{10 mm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{acknowledgement}[theorem]{Acknowledgement}
\newtheorem{algorithm}[theorem]{Algorithm}
\newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Axiom}
\newtheorem{case}[theorem]{Case}
\newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim}
\newtheorem{conclusion}[theorem]{Conclusion}
\newtheorem{condition}[theorem]{Condition}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{criterion}[theorem]{Criterion}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{Notation}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{solution}[theorem]{Solution}
\newtheorem{summary}[theorem]{Summary}
\newenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\noindent\textbf{#1.} }{\ \rule{0.5em}{0.5em}}
\newcolumntype{d}{D{.}{.}{3.4}}
\makeatletter
\def\@biblabel#1{\hspace*{-\labelsep}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Main Section}

This article includes an example of an appendix longtable with 645 rows of data in only two columns to be split into various two-column to fill one page and carry on filling over the next pages.

\bigskip

\appendix
\section{Appendix}

\begin{small}
\hfuzz\maxdimen % be quiet
\def\zz#1\\#2\\#3\\{%
#1&#2&#3\tabularnewline
\zz}
\def\endzz#1\zz{}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\begin{longtable}{
@{}
l
@{\extracolsep{0pt}}
l
@{\extracolsep{\textwidth minus \textwidth}}
l
@{\extracolsep{0pt}}
l
@{\extracolsep{\textwidth minus \textwidth}}
l
@{\extracolsep{0pt}}
l
@{}
}

    Oct-53 & 1953M10D20$^{\dagger}$ \kill

\caption{Schedule}\\
\toprule[1pt]
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Month} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Date} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Month} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Date}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Month} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Date}
\\[0.5ex]
\toprule
\endfirsthead

\caption[ ] {Schedule \textit{Continued $\ldots$}}\\
\toprule[1pt]
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Month} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Date} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Month} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Date} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Month} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Date}
\\[0.5ex]
\toprule
\endhead

\\[-2ex]
\midrule 
\\[-2ex]  
\multicolumn{6}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{\footnotesize\textit{\textbf{Notes}}:
$\dagger$ Industrial action days.}\\ 
\multicolumn{6}{r}{\textit{Continued $\ldots$}}\\ 
\endfoot

\\[-2ex]
\bottomrule[1pt]
\\[-2ex]
\multicolumn{6}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{\footnotesize\textit{\textbf{Notes}}:
$\dagger$ Industrial action days.}\\ 
\multicolumn{6}{r}{\textit{The End}}\\
\endlastfoot
\zz
Jan-49 & 1949M01D20 \\
Feb-49 & 1949M02D20 \\
Mar-49 & 1949M03D20$^{\dagger}$ \\
Apr-49 & 1949M04D20 \\
May-49 & 1949M05D20 \\
Jun-49 & 1949M06D20 \\
Jul-49 & 1949M07D20 \\
Aug-49 & 1949M08D20 \\
Sep-49 & 1949M09D20 \\
Oct-49 & 1949M10D20 \\
Nov-49 & 1949M11D20 \\
Dec-49 & 1949M12D20 \\
Jan-50 & 1950M01D20 \\
Feb-50 & 1950M02D20 \\
Mar-50 & 1950M03D20$^{\dagger}$ \\
Apr-50 & 1950M04D20 \\
May-50 & 1950M05D20 \\
Jun-50 & 1950M06D20 \\
Jul-50 & 1950M07D20 \\
Aug-50 & 1950M08D20 \\
Sep-50 & 1950M09D20 \\
Oct-50 & 1950M10D20 \\
Nov-50 & 1950M11D20 \\
Dec-50 & 1950M12D20 \\
Jan-51 & 1951M01D20 \\
Feb-51 & 1951M02D20 \\
Mar-51 & 1951M03D20 \\
Apr-51 & 1951M04D20 \\
May-51 & 1951M05D20 \\
Jun-51 & 1951M06D20 \\
Jul-51 & 1951M07D20 \\
Aug-51 & 1951M08D20 \\
Sep-51 & 1951M09D20 \\
Oct-51 & 1951M10D20 \\
Nov-51 & 1951M11D20 \\
Dec-51 & 1951M12D20 \\
Jan-52 & 1952M01D20 \\
Feb-52 & 1952M02D20 \\
Mar-52 & 1952M03D20 \\
Apr-52 & 1952M04D20 \\
May-52 & 1952M05D20 \\
Jun-52 & 1952M06D20 \\
Jul-52 & 1952M07D20 \\
Aug-52 & 1952M08D20 \\
Sep-52 & 1952M09D20 \\
Oct-52 & 1952M10D20 \\
Nov-52 & 1952M11D20 \\
Dec-52 & 1952M12D20 \\
Jan-53 & 1953M01D20 \\
Feb-53 & 1953M02D20 \\
Mar-53 & 1953M03D20 \\
Apr-53 & 1953M04D20 \\
May-53 & 1953M05D20 \\
Jun-53 & 1953M06D20 \\
Jul-53 & 1953M07D20 \\
Aug-53 & 1953M08D20 \\
Sep-53 & 1953M09D20 \\
Oct-53 & 1953M10D20$^{\dagger}$ \\
Nov-53 & 1953M11D20 \\
Dec-53 & 1953M12D20 \\
Jan-54 & 1954M01D20 \\
Feb-54 & 1954M02D20 \\
Mar-54 & 1954M03D20 \\
Apr-54 & 1954M04D20 \\
May-54 & 1954M05D20 \\
Jun-54 & 1954M06D20 \\
Jul-54 & 1954M07D20 \\
Aug-54 & 1954M08D20 \\
Sep-54 & 1954M09D20 \\
Oct-54 & 1954M10D20 \\
Nov-54 & 1954M11D20 \\
Dec-54 & 1954M12D20 \\
Jan-55 & 1955M01D20 \\
Feb-55 & 1955M02D20 \\
Mar-55 & 1955M03D20 \\
Apr-55 & 1955M04D20 \\
May-55 & 1955M05D20 \\
Jun-55 & 1955M06D20 \\
Jul-55 & 1955M07D20 \\
Aug-55 & 1955M08D20 \\
Sep-55 & 1955M09D20 \\
Oct-55 & 1955M10D20 \\
Nov-55 & 1955M11D20 \\
Dec-55 & 1955M12D20 \\
Jan-56 & 1956M01D20 \\
Feb-56 & 1956M02D20 \\
Mar-56 & 1956M03D20 \\
Apr-56 & 1956M04D20 \\
May-56 & 1956M05D20 \\
Jun-56 & 1956M06D20 \\
Jul-56 & 1956M07D20 \\
Aug-56 & 1956M08D20 \\
Sep-56 & 1956M09D20 \\
Oct-56 & 1956M10D20 \\
Nov-56 & 1956M11D20 \\
Dec-56 & 1956M12D20 \\
Jan-57 & 1957M01D20 \\
Feb-57 & 1957M02D20 \\
Mar-57 & 1957M03D20 \\
Apr-57 & 1957M04D20 \\
May-57 & 1957M05D20 \\
Jun-57 & 1957M06D20 \\
Jul-57 & 1957M07D20$^{\dagger}$ \\
Aug-57 & 1957M08D20 \\
Sep-57 & 1957M09D20 \\
Oct-57 & 1957M10D20 \\
Nov-57 & 1957M11D20 \\
Dec-57 & 1957M12D20 \\
Jan-58 & 1958M01D20 \\
Feb-58 & 1958M02D20 \\
Mar-58 & 1958M03D20 \\
Apr-58 & 1958M04D20 \\
May-58 & 1958M05D20 \\
Jun-58 & 1958M06D20 \\
Jul-58 & 1958M07D20 \\
Aug-58 & 1958M08D20 \\
Sep-58 & 1958M09D20 \\
Oct-58 & 1958M10D20 \\
Nov-58 & 1958M11D20 \\
Dec-58 & 1958M12D20 \\
Jan-59 & 1959M01D20 \\
Feb-59 & 1959M02D20 \\
Mar-59 & 1959M03D20 \\
Apr-59 & 1959M04D20 \\
May-59 & 1959M05D20$^{\dagger}$ \\
Jun-59 & 1959M06D20$^{\dagger}$ \\
Jul-59 & 1959M07D20 \\
Aug-59 & 1959M08D20 \\
Sep-59 & 1959M09D20 \\
Oct-59 & 1959M10D20 \\
Nov-59 & 1959M11D20 \\
Dec-59 & 1959M12D20 \\
Jan-60 & 1960M01D20 \\
Feb-60 & 1960M02D20 \\
Mar-60 & 1960M03D20 \\
Apr-60 & 1960M04D20 \\
May-60 & 1960M05D20 \\
Jun-60 & 1960M06D20 \\
Jul-60 & 1960M07D20 \\
Aug-60 & 1960M08D20 \\
Sep-60 & 1960M09D20 \\
Oct-60 & 1960M10D20 \\
Nov-60 & 1960M11D20 \\
Dec-60 & 1960M12D20 \\
Jan-61 & 1961M01D20 \\
Feb-61 & 1961M02D20 \\
Mar-61 & 1961M03D20 \\
Apr-61 & 1961M04D20 \\
May-61 & 1961M05D20 \\
Jun-61 & 1961M06D20 \\
Jul-61 & 1961M07D20 \\
Aug-61 & 1961M08D20 \\
Sep-61 & 1961M09D20 \\
Oct-61 & 1961M10D20 \\
Nov-61 & 1961M11D20 \\
Dec-61 & 1961M12D20 \\
Jan-62 & 1962M01D20 \\
Feb-62 & 1962M02D20 \\
Mar-62 & 1962M03D20 \\
Apr-62 & 1962M04D20 \\
May-62 & 1962M05D20 \\
Jun-62 & 1962M06D20 \\
Jul-62 & 1962M07D20 \\
Aug-62 & 1962M08D20 \\
Sep-62 & 1962M09D20 \\
Oct-62 & 1962M10D20 \\
Nov-62 & 1962M11D20 \\
Dec-62 & 1962M12D20 \\
Jan-63 & 1963M01D20 \\
Feb-63 & 1963M02D20 \\
Mar-63 & 1963M03D20$^{\dagger}$ \\
Apr-63 & 1963M04D20 \\
May-63 & 1963M05D20 \\
Jun-63 & 1963M06D20 \\
Jul-63 & 1963M07D20 \\
Aug-63 & 1963M08D20 \\
Sep-63 & 1963M09D20 \\
Oct-63 & 1963M10D20 \\
Nov-63 & 1963M11D20 \\
Dec-63 & 1963M12D20 \\
Jan-64 & 1964M01D20 \\
Feb-64 & 1964M02D20 \\
Mar-64 & 1964M03D20 \\
Apr-64 & 1964M04D20 \\
May-64 & 1964M05D20 \\
Jun-64 & 1964M06D20 \\
Jul-64 & 1964M07D20 \\
Aug-64 & 1964M08D20 \\
Sep-64 & 1964M09D20 \\
Oct-64 & 1964M10D20 \\
Nov-64 & 1964M11D20 \\
Dec-64 & 1964M12D20 \\
Jan-65 & 1965M01D20$^{\dagger}$ \\
Feb-65 & 1965M02D20 \\
Mar-65 & 1965M03D20 \\
Apr-65 & 1965M04D20 \\
May-65 & 1965M05D20 \\
Jun-65 & 1965M06D20 \\
Jul-65 & 1965M07D20 \\
Aug-65 & 1965M08D20 \\
Sep-65 & 1965M09D20 \\
Oct-65 & 1965M10D20 \\
Nov-65 & 1965M11D20 \\
Dec-65 & 1965M12D20 \\
Jan-66 & 1966M01D20 \\
Feb-66 & 1966M02D20 \\
Mar-66 & 1966M03D20 \\
Apr-66 & 1966M04D20 \\
May-66 & 1966M05D20 \\
Jun-66 & 1966M06D20 \\
Jul-66 & 1966M07D20 \\
Aug-66 & 1966M08D20 \\
Sep-66 & 1966M09D20 \\
Oct-66 & 1966M10D20 \\
Nov-66 & 1966M11D20 \\
Dec-66 & 1966M12D20 \\
Jan-67 & 1967M01D20 \\
Feb-67 & 1967M02D20 \\
Mar-67 & 1967M03D20 \\
Apr-67 & 1967M04D20 \\
May-67 & 1967M05D20 \\
Jun-67 & 1967M06D20 \\
Jul-67 & 1967M07D20 \\
Aug-67 & 1967M08D20 \\
Sep-67 & 1967M09D20 \\
Oct-67 & 1967M10D20 \\
Nov-67 & 1967M11D20 \\
Dec-67 & 1967M12D20 \\
Jan-68 & 1968M01D20 \\
Feb-68 & 1968M02D20 \\
Mar-68 & 1968M03D20 \\
Apr-68 & 1968M04D20 \\
May-68 & 1968M05D20 \\
Jun-68 & 1968M06D20 \\
Jul-68 & 1968M07D20 \\
Aug-68 & 1968M08D20 \\
Sep-68 & 1968M09D20 \\
Oct-68 & 1968M10D20 \\
Nov-68 & 1968M11D20 \\
Dec-68 & 1968M12D20 \\
Jan-69 & 1969M01D20 \\
Feb-69 & 1969M02D20 \\
Mar-69 & 1969M03D20 \\
Apr-69 & 1969M04D20 \\
May-69 & 1969M05D20 \\
Jun-69 & 1969M06D20 \\
Jul-69 & 1969M07D20 \\
Aug-69 & 1969M08D20 \\
Sep-69 & 1969M09D20 \\
Oct-69 & 1969M10D20 \\
Nov-69 & 1969M11D20 \\
Dec-69 & 1969M12D20 \\
Jan-70 & 1970M01D20 \\
\endzz\\\\
\end{longtable}
\end{small}

\label{tab:DeepHistory_GDP}%
\bigskip
\clearpage

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{Smith and Jones 2008} Smith and Jones (2008). Real Policy. ECB WP100.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```